# Making a community out of people you're following and followers in Twitter?

Tags: twitter, followers

I just read an article that explains why I've had one like out of 320 tweets. Engagement rate is extremely low. However, I do have 21 followers! I love the way Twitter helps you find like-minded people. But the mechanisms for talking to those people seems to purposely stunt it. I want to meet and talk to people. Is there a feature I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter offers several ways to engage with like-minded people who interest you:

1. **Follow** - in Twitter, following people of interest is the most basic courteous act. People you follow get notified when you do so and, given your bio and tweets interest them too, they might follow you back in return.
2. **Like** - think of a like as a semi-private gesture from you to someone whom their tweet you liked. They get notified when you do so and over time, they might notice that you like their tweets and choose to follow you back.
3. **Retweet** - a retweet is a full fledged public endorsement of someone-else's tweet. Different from a "Like" which is between you and the other person, a Retweet is literally passing the other person's tweet to your followers. Because of it's public implications, a Retweet tends to get more gratitude form the other person.
4. **Direct Message (DM)** - a DM is essentially a private message from you to another person. You can only send DMs to people who follow you. Therefore, if you followed people of interest, liked and retweeted their tweets and eventually they realize the common interests you share and follow you back, if really wished, you can DM them your thoughts in a more elaborate way.

**NOTE**: you should bare in mind that some heavy-weight Twitter users use their DMs like SMS or whatsapp and would feel odd if you'd DM them without proper context.